# How save Form as image or convert to image in java

Tags: java, jquery, image

I have a scenario,

1. User fill up the form, like registration form, on front end
2. Then user save the form - when user hit on save button ,then all the data fill up by the user is send to rest web-service( using spring ) to save the form data in db.

But I also want this

3. Want to save the image of the form also

The form is very complex and color full many logos.

What is the best to way to achieve this -

1. To convert the form in image on front end and upload to rest
2. To convert the data in form in image on the back end

The application is for both android and web

On front end using - jquery

On back end using - spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a easy and simple solution for you would be to just use the current dom and save it as a png you can use a pre-built framework like this one

https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image

which is written in pure javascript, you then could upload that generated png to your database or whatever you want to store it in.

Example:

```
var node = document.getElementById('my-node');

domtoimage.toPng(node)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
```